# Datepicker in am-pm format

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following date picker:

```
DatePicker("Time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
```

That would be using the 24h format by default like this:

[image]

How can I set it to am/pm format like this:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
DatePicker("Time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute, .dateFormat = "hh:mm a"])
```

but it's not working. How can I have the time picker (only the time, not date) in am/pm format?

Comment: I think it is based on the locale of you phone. So you’d have to use - .environment(\.locale, #YourLocale#) and set to a locale that supports AM/PM format

Comment: @CloudBalancing yeah while posting this I just noticed something, on the simulator it shows 24h time and on the xcode preview it shows am/pm. Any idea what's the right variable to get this using the environment? To check what the user is using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picker will respect the locale. So, if you what to overrule the system settings you can set the desired locale on the picker like this:

```
picker.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en")
```